# Execute SQL statement with terraform on Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a SQL query on my newly created Redshift database with terraform. I want the sql query to execute after my database in created. I am referencing a SQL script in VSCode. I am not getting any error after running terraform apply but there is no change to my database. I am just trying to create a script that creates schemas. my code looks like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "db_setup" {
  depends_on = ["aws_redshiftserverless_namespace.xxxx"]
  provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "psql -h 'redshift-serverless.id.region.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com' -p xxxx -U ${aws_redshiftserverless_namespace.user_name} -d ${aws_redshiftserverless_namespace.db_name}  -f '${path.module}/scripts/xxxx.sql'"

    environment = {
      PGPASSWORD = "${aws_redshiftserverless_namespace.xxxx}"
    }
  }
  
}
```

is there anything i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this `pyqsl` command work on its own? Only you can check what the command actually does and if it works.

Comment: Hi Marcin, do you mean to replace psql with pyqsl in my code?I tried that but it doesn't work